# What is the resolution of the best publicily available satellite images from the 1970s and 1980s, for the southern hemisphere?

Tags: imagery, satellite, history, historical-imagery, south-america

What motivates the question is a neighborhood disagreement involving my parents, that developed as follows:

- Dad bought a house in early 70s, moved there. The house was adjacent to a vacant lot, used as a passage between our street and the back street;
- Dad married in early 80s, Mom moved in;
- Around mid-80s Neighbor A buys half the vacant lot, builds house there, moves in;
- In early 2000s Neighbor A sells house to another person, Neighbor B. Neighbor B moves in;
- Around 2010 Neighbor B claims side wall from Dad/Mom's house invades his property. Disagreement starts. Neighbor B keeps complaining often. My parents just ignore it as a baseless claim;
- In late 2022 Neighbor B sues my parents.

To back his lawsuit, Neighbor B actually produced a document filed to the local property registry by either himself or Neighbor A. The document appears legitimate, but it has some information on it that just doesn't add up, not limited to the property measures. For example, it says there was a house in the location since 1966, what is not true, according to my Dad. Also, it says Neighbor A bought said house in 1990, also not true, given Neighbor A actually built the house in mid-80s, in the previously vacant lot, and moved there before the 90s.

So, I suspect somehow, someone managed to file a record with incorrect data to the local property registry, and now that is being used to sue my parents. I also suspect Neighbor B probably knows the data in the record has problems, but decided to proceed with the lawsuit anyway, because it sat on the matter for more than 10 years, and only filed the lawsuit after another elderly neighbor that lived nearby passed away in 2021, victim of COVID-19. This elderly neighbor already lived in the street before my Dad arrived, so his testimony could potentially settle the matter.

Currently we are trying to find a lawyer with some experience dealing with problems like this. Also we are doing some brainstorming trying to find ways to show Neighbor B papers were based on fake data. If the utility companies have good record keeping, I think we can show our house existed since at least the 70s, but Neighbor B will be unable to do the same going back before mid 80s.

Back in the 80s there was no Google Earth, but I think there was already some Nasa satellites taking pictures from Earth. If one of them photographed our city back then, and had good enough resolution, that would be also a nice proof. The problem is the resolution should be great enough to show a urban plot of land about 4m x 30m was vacant in early 80s, instead of occupied by a house since 1966 as Neighbor B's document says. I don't think such precision was possible in the 80s and before, but to be sure, I'm asking this question. The place where my parents live is in South America, in a city close to 7deg15min south, 39deg21min west.

Comment: Is there no local archive that maybe contains such data? Is there a local historian or photographer that documented the area in the 80's? In your country, is there no official housing registry (building permission) that clearly shows when a house was constructed? Does the architectural style of the house or the material used give any hint? Asking at local construction companies that were involved building the house?

Comment: @Babel Record keeping in the region was poor. There are local archives, they are called "cartórios" here. But most people didn't care to get a nice official registry back then, because of the expenses. People just redacted their own buy/sell contracts as properties were passed along. After the end of the dictatorship things started getting better, and official registry more affordable. But my dad never cared to get a official document, the one he has is of the old type, even featuring archaic, non-metric units. I think the neighbor got his official one close to 2000. He's better documented.

Comment: Also, I intend to file a inquiry in the prefecture for any existing photos of the area. But back then cameras and supplies were very expensive. In general people didn't have cameras at home. In special occasions, like marriages, they hired professional photograpers to take some carefully staged photos. It is quite funny to see the solemn faces of people in old photos, because they were afraid of blinking in the wrong moment and end spoiling the photo.

Comment: Any local plans/maps from the period documenting buildings as well?

Comment: @Babel I don't know yet. That's another thing to inquire the prefecture about. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: I think this is a question more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange than here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google Earth, zoom in to the region of your interest. Than activate the time slider and shift it to the date of interest - if images are available (see screenshot below). For the area of Juazeiro do Norte, the available images from the 1980's, the images seem to have a too low resolution to identify individual buildings, but you should check for yourself. Oldest available, detailed/high resolution image is from 2004.

Also check these link lists with resources of (historical) satellite images:

- https://gisgeography.com/free-historical-imagery-viewers/
- https://www.historicaerials.com/
- https://eos.com/blog/historical-satellite-images/
- https://skywatch.com/free-sources-of-satellite-data/

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know Google Earth had this time-travel functionality. Unfortunately the 1985 images are too coarse. Even entire city blocks can barely be discerned as smudges. It seems we'll have to prove our case using other kinds of evidence.